# Failed installation of GD library on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gd

I am trying to install GD library on my Debian server, but the following error appears:

```
# apt-get install php5-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 libt1-5 php5-common php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libt1-5 php5-gd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-common php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
4 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 3120kB of archives.
After this operation, 545kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php5-mysql php5-mcrypt libapache2-mod-php5 php5-common libt1-5 php5-gd
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main php5-mysql 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main php5-mcrypt 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main libapache2-mod-php5 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main php5-common 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main libt1-5 5.1.2-3+lenny1
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main php5-gd 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-mcrypt_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/t/t1lib/libt1-5_5.1.2-3+lenny1_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 128.101.240.212 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get a different IP for security.debian.org (195.20.242.89). Flush the DNS cache and try again, it's possible that they've moved IPs:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/nscd restart
```

And then follow the instructions and run

```
apt-get update
```

Before trying to install it again

Comment: +1 get the same error when I had forgot to run apt-get update